# hide package loading message when I render R markdown

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown

I can't get this `dplyr` package loading message to go away:

> package 'dplyr successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

And here is my current code:

```r
g <- df$Finished
h <- append(g, rep("dummy",519))
i <- data.frame(counts <- table(h))
row.names(i) <- c("In progress", "Completed", "Invited")
colnames(i) <- c("gh", "Count")
i = subset(i,select = -c(gh))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", quiet = TRUE, message=FALSE))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE, invisible()))
ii<- i %>%
  arrange(desc(Count))
u <- ii %>% mutate(Percentage = (ii[,1]/519)*100)
print(u)
```

It even says "cannot remove prior installation of package 'dplyr'

Comment: I rolled back your redaction because your question doesn't make any sense without being able to see the code.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a package *loading* message, it's a package *installation* message (which is why all the message suppression won't help). You probably shouldn't install the package every time.  Try something like

```r
if (!require("dplyr")) {
   install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", 
         quiet = TRUE, message=FALSE))
}
```

If all else fails you could probably use `capture.output()` to make sure you had intercepted all output.

Comment: where exacly should I add it?

Comment: woohooo got it. It was due to installing it again

Comment: That''s what I was trying to say.  If this answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: Please accept Ben's answer if it was useful :)